# C#: Excel Ribbon Addin change cursor to wait while calling method

Tags: c#, excel

I have created an Excel Addin with a Ribbon (my first one) that has buttons that calls a method that runs a Stored Procedure.
I would like to set the cursor to wait whilst the method is running.
have tried cursor.wait but that seems to be form windows forms.

I know I should use xlMousePointer but cannot find any example code.

Many Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation I have resolved the issue with the following code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        XlMousePointer originalCursor = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor;

        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = XlMousePointer.xlWait;

        Method1();

        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Cursor = originalCursor;
    }
```